# Autohotkey: binding win key

Tags: autohotkey

I've got a keyboard without the Win key (a legendary Model M!), so I want to bind it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>esc</kbd>.

I tried those things, but that doesn't work -_-

```
LCtrl & Escape::LWin
```

or

```
LCtrl & Escape::
Send {LWin}
return
```

If I simply do:

```
Escape::LWin
```

or

```
Escape::
Send {LWin}
return
```

It's OK...

I also got another function that works OK like this:

```
^!F2::Send {Volume_Up 100}
```

So right now, can't figure what's wrong... Probably the misuse with the "&"?

Any idea?

Thank you!

---

After answer 1: I found this solution if I want to use the win key for combination (Win + e, Win + d, etc.):

```
^Esc::
KeyWait Ctrl        ;wait until Ctrl is up
 Send {LWin Down}   ;send left Windows key down
 sleep, 500
 Send {LWin Up}     ;send left Windows key up
Return
```

That way, when I depress <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, I've got 500ms to type the 2nd key.

Comment: does `^Esc::LWin` work?

Comment: Nope :/ Same thing: nothing happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, then 
<kbd>LWin</kbd> is sent by AHK, but you are still holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so the result of this 'cooperation' is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LWin</kbd> which is ignored by Windows.

Solution:

```
^Esc::
 KeyWait Ctrl    ;wait until Ctrl is up
 Send {LWin}     ;send left Windows key
Return
```

Comment: Thanks! The win touch is emulated that way :D But does that mean that I can't use this combination for "Win + [key]"? For example if I want to "win + e" to open a new folder?

Comment: add this?? `Input,k,L1 T0.5,,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: @benichka - I'm not aware of that possibility. Maybe you can remap your CapsLoack key ([Question](http://superuser.com/questions/333445/simulating-the-windows-key-on-an-old-keyboard), [Answer1](http://superuser.com/a/333474/287473), [Answer2](http://superuser.com/a/333489/287473))  and then you get these keyboard combinations back.

Comment: JoeDF, didn't try it as I found a way ^^ @miroxlav, will probably do that for the long term! Nice to know, thank you :)